# What's the default length in tabulary?

Tags: tables, tabulary

How to change table length in `tabulary` without changing the option in tabulary brackets
`\begin{tabulary}{length} 
... 
\end{tabulary}`
I used 24 cm (`landscape` environment), points etc., but it doesn't work, so is there other way to do this? Like leaving length `{}` empty and adding sth in preamble, maybe changing .sty?
`tabulary` is great table generator environment (it makes your table great), so I'd rather stick with it than changing to `tabular` which sucks in every aspect.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There is no default width for `tabulary`. The width has to be set in the first argument of the environment. Instead of setting a numeric width (say, `24cm`), consider using something like `\textwidth` (or `\textheight` if inside a `sidewaystable` environment).

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think there would be a default? It is a latex mandatory argument in `{..}` if it had a default value the manual would have mentioned it and the length argument would be in `[...]`.

Perhaps you are looking for

```
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{LLL}
 a&b&c
\end{tabular}
```

so that it makes a full width table to whatever is the current width at that point, but it is hard to be sure as the question is rather vague (I don't understand the reference to `landscape` at all)

Comment: You'd need a column specification in there as well, I suppose.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. er yes and some table data and and `\end{tabulary}`  :-) I was just suggesting what the OP should have instead  of the `\begin{tabulary}{length}` in the question

Comment: Well, yes. I guess my comment was made partly because the OP does have (a placeholder for) table data and `\end{tabulary}`, but no table preamble. Could just be a mistake of course, but it would explain why it "doesn't work", if the code was actually like that. Anyways, some clarifications by the OP is still in order.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I'll add something, it will save someone copy-pasteing broken code in future years

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{CcCcC} ` works ! thanks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle one more thing. Is it possible to adjust table with `tabulary` to fit the page perfectly without using scaling?

Comment: @devloon you mean vertical and horizontal at same time?  No (and never use scaling on tables!)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle okay, finally I got everything I need for now on tables. :d `\tymax`  helped a lot. Thanks for doing all this amazing work for latex and its community.